# Vue JS plugin using rollup and p11n not building import files that are not javascript error

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, rollup

I'm using Vue JS to build a plugin and am using the [p11n](https://github.com/kazupon/vue-cli-plugin-p11n) module. I've built my components and everything works fine when serving via `npm run serve`, but when trying to build the project via `npm run build` which essentially is running: `vue-cli-service build` I get the following error regardless of what version I use:

```js
 ERROR  Error: Unexpected token (Note that you need plugins to import files that are not JavaScript)
Error: Unexpected token (Note that you need plugins to import files that are not JavaScript)
    at error (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/application-compiler-gui/node_modules/rollup/dist/shared/node-entry.js:5400:30)
    at Module.error (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/application-compiler-gui/node_modules/rollup/dist/shared/node-entry.js:9824:16)
    at tryParse (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/application-compiler-gui/node_modules/rollup/dist/shared/node-entry.js:9717:23)
    at Module.setSource (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/application-compiler-gui/node_modules/rollup/dist/shared/node-entry.js:10080:33)
    at Promise.resolve.catch.then.then.then (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/application-compiler-gui/node_modules/rollup/dist/shared/node-entry.js:12366:20)
```

No idea how to fix this, I've tried installing the Vue JS rollup plugin, no luck :(

Comment: I have the same issue as well. How did you config your rollup.config.js?